# I can not add a slug url to my django app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use slug url like /post/5post-title or /post/post-title.
I am currently using plain URLs in the form of /post/123 , I tried a lot of methods, and all failed.. 
Now I am trying "Migrating from primary-key based lookups" from https://keyerror.com/blog/slug-fields-an-alternative-approach

and I got a broswer error 'Too many redirections'... How to solve this problem？ Or do you have a better method to change the plain url to slug url?

My models:

```
class Post(models.Model):

title,article and someFields.......

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

def slug(self):
    return slugify(self.title)
```

and my urls:

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w-]+))?$',views.detail,name='detail'),]
```

my views:

```
def detail(request,pk,slug=None):
post=get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
if slug!=post.slug():
    return redirect(post, permanent=True)

return render(request,'blog/detail.html',context=context)
```

---

use a SlugField models and remove pk:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=70)
body=models.TextField()
created_time=models.DateTimeField()
modified_time=models.DateTimeField()
excerpt=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
tags=models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True)
author=models.ForeignKey(User)
views=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
excerpt=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
sluglookup = models.SlugField(
    unique=True,
    default=Post.slug,
    max_length=15,)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

def increase_views(self):
    self.views+=1
    self.save(update_fields=['views'])
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if not self.excerpt:
        md=markdown.Markdown(extensions=[
            'markdown.extensions.extra',
            'markdown.extensions.codehilite',
            ])
        self.excerpt=strip_tags(md.convert(self.body))[:54]
    super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
def slug(self):
    return slugify(self.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the loop is a problem not in your slug logic, but in your 404 page logic. Based on the above, you're using the URLs incorrectly. Your regex looks for `/post/<pk>/<slug>`. You are using the URL `/post/<pk><slug>` (note the extra `/`). So `/post/5post-title` should really be `/post/5/post-title`.

Also, if you're really interested in using a pure slug-based system, you should probably use a `SlugField` as is later in the example and remove the primary key altogether.

```
lookup = models.SlugField(
    unique=True,
    default=self.slug, # This is not from the tutorial, it's a modification
    # to demonstrate here.
    max_length=13,
)
```

You'd then want a URL:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)?$',views.detail,name='detail'),
```

And a view:

```
def detail(request,slug=None):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,lookup=slug)

    # You probably have to pass the post into the render function, that
    # will vary, based on how you've defined it in your template
    return render(request,'blog/detail.html',context=context)
```

Comment: I added a def slug method ( return slugify( self.title )) under the Post model , then added the lookup Slugfield,  when I save it , the error raised " (defalut = self.slug) name 'self' is not defined "  How to avoid this problem?

Comment: `<ModelName>.slug`

Comment: after change to default = Post.slug  it still raised "Post is not defined".....  I put the source code up

Answer (score 0):

I would recommned to either put a breakpoint on `return redirect(post, permanent=True)` or a log before it saying what is the value of `slug` and what is the value of `post.slug()`.

As far as I can see, that `if` seems to be the only part where a recursive redirection bug could occur, given the source; of course, I could be wrong.